# UITableView, select cell with colour different than blue?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I've got a table view, how can I select a cell with different colour? Or how can I set the image of selection? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily change the cells selection style to gray:

```
[myTableView setSelectionStyle: UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray];
```

Or you can change the `contentView's` `backgroundColor` in the `willDisplayCell` delegate:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

Another way would be to create a custom cell and change the color of the Background.

Comment: Thanks) but in CustomCell class within init method [self setSelectionStyle:...];

Answer (score 1):

```
UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
[bgColorView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[cell setSelectedBackgroundView:bgColorView];
[bgColorView release];
```

Presumably you could do the same with a UIImageView as well

```
UIImageView *bgImageView = [[UIImageView imageNamed:@"Your Image"];
[cell setSelectedBackgroundView:bgImageView];
[bgImageView release];
```